# Error when read Column value from excel with java using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to read the excel file, so I can reference the column index by name, and I do like that :

```
package main;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcel {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        InputStream fs = new FileInputStream("/.../ListProducts.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);



        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>(); //Create map
        HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0); //Get first row
        //following is boilerplate from the java doc
        short minColIx = row.getFirstCellNum(); //get the first column index for a row
        short maxColIx = row.getLastCellNum(); //get the last column index for a row
        for(short colIx=minColIx; colIx<maxColIx; colIx++) { //loop from first to last index
        HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(colIx); //get the cell
        map.put(cell.getStringCellValue(),cell.getColumnIndex()); //add the cell contents (name of column) and cell index to the map
        }

        List<ReportRow> listOfDataFromReport = new ArrayList<ReportRow>();
        for(int x = 1; x<=sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); x++){
         ReportRow rr = new ReportRow(); 
         HSSFRow dataRow = sheet.getRow(x); 

         int idxForColumn1 = map.get("Id"); 
         int idxForColumn2 = map.get("Name"); 
         int idxForColumn3 = map.get("Price"); 

         HSSFCell cell1 = dataRow.getCell(idxForColumn1); 
         HSSFCell cell2 = dataRow.getCell(idxForColumn2); 
         HSSFCell cell3 = dataRow.getCell(idxForColumn3);  

         rr.setColumn1(cell1.getStringCellValue()); 
         rr.setColumn2(cell2.getStringCellValue());
         rr.setColumn3(cell3.getStringCellValue());

         listOfDataFromReport.add(rr);

        }

        for(int j = 0; j< listOfDataFromReport.size();j++){
               System.out.println("Column 1 Value: " +   listOfDataFromReport.get(j).getColumn1());
            //etc...    
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


}
```

When I run the program, I get this in output :

```
null
```

I have already the excel file in the correct destination and with the right name of column.

**EDIT**

When I add `e.printStackTrace();`, I get this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at main.ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:51)

null
```

**EDIT2**

I notice that variables of `setColumn1,setColumn2,...` methods are `double`.

I do this :

```
rr.setColumn1(cell1.getNumericCellValue()); 
rr.setColumn2(cell2.getNumericCellValue());
rr.setColumn3(cell3.getNumericCellValue());
```

I get the following error when I try to run the program to read data:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get 
 a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell at 
 org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.typeMismatch(HSSFCell.java:654)
 at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.getNumericCellValue(HSSFCell.java:679)
```

Comment: Ye, I think that output is actually the `Exception` message, not the printing of a list. Try doing `e.printStackTrace()` in catch block instead to see actual error.

Comment: Ok you can see my edit above...

Answer (score 0):

Well I got kinda different opinion than @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ. Assuming names of the columns are correct in your code, I think that this may be the problem:

`for(int x = 1; x<=sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); x++){`

Let's say number of physical rows is `3`, so they are numbered `0, 1, 2` and you are iterating till `3`, thus when you trying to get the cell later it throws the `NullPointerException`, because there is no such row.

Try doing `x < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();` (less than, not less/equal than) in the `for` loop I mentioned earlier.